# SpriteKit move node with physics rather than updating position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My main character moves by touching and holding him and then moving your finger left or right to move the character. To do this I just simply update the node's x position (walks left and right on a flat surface) in `touchesMoved()` with the x position of the touch location, and apply an animation depending on the direction he's moving.

I want to kind of take this to the next level and accomplish the same effect, but using physics, so that when I'm done moving him and release my finger, he may slide a little bit in the direction he was moving given the speed I was moving him at, if that makes sense. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this effect?

Would I have to do as I'm currently doing and update the position as it moves, but also apply a force/impulse at the same time? Kind of confused on how to approach this

Comment: You should be fine by *just* giving a node a force, impulse or velocity. No need to update the position as well, that might actually create not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the physics body via force, impulse, or velocity will automatically update the player position.

So you will have to play around with the correct way to accomplish your goal. But based on this, what I would suggest is replace your `.position` code with `.physicsBody!.velocity` code in your touchesMoved. Then, on your touchesEnded, you can apply a bit of an impulse to give the player that little bit of an "on ice" effect to keep them going a tad.

You will need to experiment with how much velocity you want to get the character to move at the correct speed, and then you will need to play with the impulse figures as well to get it just right.

This could get a bit tricky though, in touchesMoved... because at some point you will want to reset the velocity to 0 (so they stop moving when your finger stops).

To do that, you will need to to use the .`previousLocation` from your `touch` object, and compare the distance of X moved. if the distance X moved is >0 (or some deadzone threshold) then apply the velocity; if the deltaX is 0, then set the velocity to 0.

This may actually be more complicated than just using `.position` to move the character, then having the character slide a bit with physics on touchesEnded.

You will have to play with it to get it right.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try this approach! Also, do you know why my character would be missing when I launch after enabling `isDynamic = true`? He should be in contact with the ground below him, and also affectedByGravity is false. I can't seem to figure out why he has disappeard. I added some code to my question. I also tried constraining him above the floor but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Brejuro it's possible the affectedByGravity command didn't go through. Make sure the pb you are working with isn't `nil`. Also, you can use simple `print` to see where he is off to (above, below, etc). You should probably make a new question though, and I can answer there with how to keep him in bounds. since this is now 2 separate questions in 1

Comment: Alrighty, thanks. I'll leave it at that, I was just thinking it may have been simple enough for a comment. I'll start working on implementing this!

Comment: @Brejuro I have a keepPlayerInBounds() function I can share with you if you have another question. This is a pretty common thing with physics bodies and platforms. it can (will) be frustrating at time!